# Why does Virtual Box VMs add a Floppy Drive by default

Tags: virtualbox, security, virtual-machine, default-settings, floppy

Whenever I create a new VM, a floppy drive is added by default. I don't think I've ever needed to use a virtual floppy drive.

Seeing that there have been hypervisor vulnerabilities that exploit virtual floppy drives, wouldn't it make sense to add as little virtual devices as possible by default and have the user add them if they need them?

Comment: It doesn't for Linux machines, at least not for me. Are you maybe mistaking the BIOS setting with "the drive" proper?

Comment: You are correct @TNierath. The floppy drive is added by default in the boot order but not in storage devices.

Comment: Good, you can ignore that. It's just a BIOS setting.